# Updating one State with two fields?

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I am trying to update my state data based on the users input in two fields and I'm not sure if Im going about it the right way.

The parent component `Encounter.js` holds the state I will try and limit the amount of code I add here so my issue is clear. So in `ComponentDidUpdate` I set the state with an object and create an update function to update the state. I pass the two values inside my state to another component `PatientInfo` along with the update state function:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
if (this.props.details && this.props.details.medicalIntake && !prevProps.details.medicalIntake) {
      this.setState({ pertinentMedications: {
        covid19Protocol: this.props.details.medicalIntake.pertinentMedications.covid19Protocol,
        note: "" || this.props.details.medicalIntake.pertinentMedications.notes
      }})
    }
}

pertinentMedicationsChange = (newValues) => {
    this.props.setIdleTime();
    this.props.setState({pertinentMedications: newValues});
  }

return (

<PatientInfo
covid19Protocol={this.state.pertinentMedications.covid19Protocol}
pertinentMedicationsNote={this.state.pertinentMedications.note}
pertinentMedicationsChange={this.pertinentMedicationsChange}
/>
)
```

`PatientInfo.js` simply passes the props down.

```
<PertinentMedications
     covid19Protocol={this.props.covid19Protocol}
     pertinentMedicationsNote={this.props.pertinentMdicationsNote}
     pertinentMedicationsChange={this.props.pertinentMedicationsChange}
/>
```

`PertinentMedications.js` is where the user input will be collected:

```
const PertinentMedications = ({
  covid19Protocol,
  pertinentMedicationsNote,
  pertinentMedicationsChange
  }) => {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(covid19Protocol)
const onClick = (field, value) => {
    setIsChecked(!isChecked)
    pertinentMedicationsChange( {[field]: value})
}

const onNoteChange = (field, value) => {
    pertinentMedicationsChange( {[field]: value})
}
    return(
        <ContentBlock title="Pertinent Medications and Supplements">
        <CheckToggle onChange={() => onClick("covid19Protocol", !covid19Protocol)} checked={isChecked}>
          <p>Patient has been receiving the standard supportive care and supplements as per COVID-19 protocol.</p>
        </CheckToggle>
        <Input 
        type="textarea"
        name="pertinentMedications"
        onChange={e => onNoteChange("notes" ,e.target.value)}
        value={pertinentMedicationsNote}
        />
        
      </ContentBlock> 
    )
}

export default PertinentMedications;
```

My true question lies within the `pertinentMedicationsChange` function as Im not sure how to take the data im getting from the `PertinentMedications` component and format it to be placed in the state. First Im not sure if I can update the state the way im trying to with these two independent fields that send their data to this function to change the state? And If it is possible Im not sure how to properly setup the key value pairs when i call setState. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you are calling `this.props.setState` instead of `this.setState`. Second, this.setState also accepts a function which first param is the previous state. In this way you can use it to prevent its key values saved from pertinentMedications to be overwritten. fwiw, it's better to be consistent, not mixing hooks with react component based.

```
pertinentMedicationsChange = (newValues) => {
this.props.setIdleTime();
this.setState((state) => ({
    // you create a new object with previous values, while newValues updates the proper keys, but not removing other keys 
    pertinentMedications: { ...state.pertinentMedications,...newValues}
  }); 
)};
```